# Printing an ArrayList from a different method

Tags: java, arraylist, printf

Design a function whose responsibility is to display the prime number array nicely. It should display the contents of the array 10 per line. A combination of print and println would be needed. Display each
number in a field of width 7 (use printf).

Here is what I have, but I'm not sure if correct.

```
public  static void printArray(ArrayList<Integer> primes){
    System.out.printf("%7s", primes);
    if (prrimeCount % 10 == 0){
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. I believe the question is asking you to display the elements within the primes `ArrayList`. To do this, you should consider using a `for` loop to iterate over all elements. To display 10 per line, you may need to determine whether your loop increment is divisible by 10 using `%`.

Comment: Not sure if correct? Run it and see if it prints what the directions said it should print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public  static void printArray(ArrayList<Integer> primes){
    // You need to have a counter as you iterate over the list
    int count = 1;
    // Integer is autoboxed into an int when interating over prime
    for(int prime : primes){
        // "%7d" instead of "%7s" as d is used for integer but s is used for strings
        System.out.printf("%7d ", prime);
        // count++ will icrement count after this statement is called
        if (count++ % 10 == 0){
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("%7s", primes);
```

this will throw an exception `primes` is an `Arraylist` but `%7s` requires a `String` .